# How do I write seleniuim code for identifying the elements on a tab that keep changing its position?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do I write seleniuim code for identifying the elements on a tab that keep changing its position? For ex: if a tab has names like "Apple", "Banana", "Oranges", "GrapeFuit" etc., then I should be able to select the option called "Oranges" (which is in 3rd position) even when its position is moved to 2nd or 4th or 1st?

Comment: Could you share the HTML page code?

Comment: you can write generic xpath that will identify element based on its text.

Comment: You can find the elements with their name. `driver.findElement(By.name("name"));`

Comment: @Würgspaß .. I dont have a code , but I am looking to write one for the above said scenario.I have gone through various examples listed in this site. But nothing has compensated so far. so any inputs regarding this are most welcome.

Comment: @Sudharsan Selvaraj ... since I am new to selenium I am not sure exactly if that works. I was told that xpath cannot be an ideal example in this scenario.